# Note 10 Plus Stuck with Partial Flight Mode (Faded Blue). What does this mean? Is this an indication of hardware failure?

Tags: connection-issues, sim-card, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, airplane-mode

I haven't yet come across a situation where factory reset didn't resolve the issue. This one is very intriguing to me as I could not conclude why the phone could stay in the partial flight mode (faded blue). It may be a coincidence, but it happened sometime after the firmware update. However, it doesn't look like a widespread issue to assume it is a bug. I have attached an image that shows flight mode in faded blue. It stays that way until I switch to Wi-Fi calling or remove the SIM card from the tray. I cannot select networks from the settings - "Error while searching for networks."

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Wipe cache partition
2. Clear SIM cache, grant permissions, network rest, restart device
3. Multiple resets with flight mode on and off, finally did a Factory rest
4. Used ODIN flashed with latest stock ROM
5. Used ODIN flashed with  a year-old ROM - system performed updates as well
6. Used ADB shell to enable cell in airplane mode, no impact. ADB mode shows flight mode was off.
7. Replaced with new SIM card, no difference

Based on the above steps, it looks like this is probably a hardware issue, but I would be relieved if it comes from experts. No drops or physical damages to the phone. I haven't read anywhere that partial flight mode results from hardware failure. However, neither ADB made any difference to conclude it as a software/GUI issue. If there aren't solutions left, I can make peace with my phone.

I would appreciate your comments and inputs.

[image]

Comment: So if you touch the Flight mode icon to enable/disable it nothing happens? Have you checked logcat for errors when you touch Flight mode icon?

Comment: Hi @Robert - thanks for responding. I just learned what logcat is after seeing your response. I see a lot running log with an ability to filter on verbose, error, warning, etc. Is there anything particular should I be looking at? How can I capture log specific to toggle? Also, when I run 'adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_radios' - it shows nfc, wimax - so technically cell and wifi should still work, right?  What's strange is airplane mode when toggled should either be grey or blue- what does half blue indicate? any persistent lock?

Comment: Especially on Samsung devices logcat is pretty verbose to my experience. I usually open logcat, wait until the old message have scrolled by and then make the action I am interested in. Then directly after making the action I press Ctrl+C to stop logcat. How the airplane icon should look I don't know, I don't have a recent Samsung device and such UI elements always look different between manufacturers and Android version.